# How to change the address at FAT(or similar) to change the location of file?

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, symbolic-link

I have a huge file which is about 67 GB is size. It takes a long time to move this file from one drive to another.

So is there a way, from which I can change its memory address(I dont know the correct term for this) to point it as if it was in different drive.

Comment: We can't give a proper answer without knowing why you want it on the other drive.

Comment: @ignacio vazques-abrams, I told you the reason, 1) many very large files 2) long time to copy

Comment: sounds like you're looking for a symbolic link (or the windows equivalent).  see @nifle's answer.

Comment: at least i can not answer that question based upon what i read. symbolic links do not transfer the data from one drive to another so you still have to wait long to get the data when read via the other drive. hard links only work on the same filesystem. moving a file implies that the old location is not available any more. it is absolutely unclear what Starx really wants (at least for me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is `filesystem links` you create them by using the command `mklink`

**mklink [[/D] | [/H] | [/J]] link target**

```
* /D – Creates a directory symbolic link. Default is a file symbolic link.
* /H – Creates a hard link instead of a symbolic link.
* /J – Creates a Directory Junction.
```

To find out more read this : [Windows File Junctions, Symbolic Links and Hard Links](http://ipggi.wordpress.com/2009/09/07/windows-file-junctions-symbolic-links-and-hard-links/)
or
this: [wikipage on symbolic links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link)

Comment: could you please give me an example as well

Comment: bottom line the files will need to be moved once at least!